# From two dice (6 sided). How can I find the numbers that give the sum of 9 in C++? (e.g die1 + die2 = 9)

Tags: c++

It loops 1-6 and assign two values, num1 and num2.there's something wrong with logical operation/if statement that it's not working in first place for some reason. Any help? (I edited my question)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num1, num2;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; ++i){
        int num1 = i;

        }

    for (int x = 1; x <= 6; ++x){
        int num2 = x;
    }

    if (num1 + num2 == 9){
        cout << num1 << " + " << num2 << " = " << " 9 " << endl;

    }
}
```

Comment: Define "but I failed". What went wrong? Did you get an error because of the stray `{`? Did it not give you the expected output?

Comment: `std::cout << "{3, 6}, {4, 5}, {5,4}, {6, 3}\n";`

Comment: Great question! It is not uncommon for beginners to be unable to pass these first steps, most of programming is infact about following known templates and not reinventing the wheel. The construct you are looking for here is what is called a nested loop.

Comment: @Hi-IloveSO no nested loop is needed here

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 but it is the simplest way for a beginner to learn about loops

Comment: You need to tell us the numbers on each die. No implementation should assume the dice are the same and they have six sides, unless you tell us that. Which you haven't.

Comment: Woah guys, what's just happened? I just asked a question and you're assuming whether my question is pointless or good? asked it because I have no one to help me but you! I'm just having ideas to practice programming like you were doing for sure. If you are saying there's no nesting needed here, just tell me how, I'm a complete beginner, no one was born programming anyway. 
Thanks for those who helped.

Comment: what got lost in the discussion is what actually needs to improved on your question: Explain in details what the code is supposed to do and what it does instead. Where in your code do you check if they add up to `9` ? The question is currently stated in a way that invites answers that just present you the code, because we cannot know what prevents you from adding the results of the dices and see if they add up to 9. Did you try anything more than the code you posted? Anything helps us to help you. "Any help?" isnt a specific question

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) might be of help. Also pay an additional attention to the first comment.

Comment: before writing code you should always make up your mind what code to write. Consider you roll first one dice and get a `6`, what must the other dice show to get a sum of `9`? If you can answer that then you already know how to solve it without a nested loop

Comment: I thought the question was clear enough, my bad!
I'm going to edit more on the question, even though I already got the answer to it. I surely did try more than I posted but I didn't know I could add them like that (die[x] + die[x] == 9) I just started lists. I had to put anything in the code body because I can't leave it empty. Thank you.

Comment: Hope it's clear enough now. is it?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 hey, I just tried your solution and it worked! I surely didn't take all that time to do it but I didn't have time. It's way simpler, no need for lists, just one for loop and if statement.

    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; ++i){

        int sol = 9 - i;

            if ( sol < 7 ){
               cout << sol;
            }
        }
I'm really grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't tested it, but I would try:

```
for (loop in your first dice){
    for (loop in your second dice){
        add the 2 numbers together;
        if (the sum is equal to 9) {
            cout << sum;
        }
    }
}
```

The double for loop should check every number with all the numbers of the second dice and check if they equal 9.

**EDIT**
Changed code for pseudo-code

Comment: Why reveal the entire solution? Do you expect a beginner to learn from this? Slight inaccuracy though, the die isn't looped through twice, it is being looped through several times concurrently.

Comment: Thank you, I'm fairly new too, just wanting to help. I've changed a bit my answer to reflect what you just said.

Comment: Thanks! I actually used the nested loops but I didn't know I could sum them like this, just started with lists though.
Now, I'm trying to do it with one list and loop through it twice.

Answer (score -1):

You should use double nested loops and check the sum of the values from each dice.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int die[6] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int die2[6] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

    int i, x;

    for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i){
        for (x = 0; x < 6; ++x){
            if (die[i] + die2[x] == 9){
                cout << die[i] << ' ' << die2[x] << '\n';
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: why nested loops? When one dice shows `i` the other must show `9-i` to get a sum of `9`. Well, partly a rhetorical question, as this seems to be exercise about loops\

Comment: I would suggest not revealing the entire solution. Noone learns anything.

Comment: @Hi-IloveSO Stack Overflow isn't a site for asking questions and getting riddles. It isn't a site for asking questions and getting quizzes. It's a site for asking questions and getting answers. Edit : Questions containing only code are incomplete, but providing code with an explanation is fine.